# Why is this site having trouble registering click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I have a map made with d3 that has title that I want to display as hover over tool tip. It correctly handles mouse click events for panning and zooming. However, it does not handle mouse overs for tools tips.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="mapwrapper">
    <div id="map">
        <svg width...>
```

If I set a jquery handler for any mouse event (click/mouseover) it will fire for map wrapper or map, but not for anything in the SVG.

```
$("#mapwrapper").on("mouseover", function() { //same for click events...
    alert("mapwrapper"); //fires
});
$("#map").on("mouseover", function() {
    alert("map");  //fires
}); 
$("svg").on("mouseover", function() {
    alert("map");   //does not fire
});
```

I've tried several methods of displaying tooltips and they don't work. I've also tried to setup a simple jquery mouseover alert (just displaying a popup when you run your mouse over an SVG element with a certain class) and that doesn't work. So clearly something is messing up the mouseover events on the SVG on the site. I know d3 has "events" -- although I don't know much about how they work.

**Interestingly, if I copy and paste the HTML into a new document and then load that document the SVG with register click events**

**I have set the [pointer events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEvents) property on the SVG to visible and get the same behavior**

How do I debug this problem?

Comment: I did not downvote the question but do have some suggestions on how to make it better. Consider including some code in the question so that the it doesn't go _stale_ after the site has been taken down. Also, that would give us an idea of _how_ you are trying to solve the problem and, thus, give you a better answer. :)

Comment: @musically_ut added some code to clarify

Comment: The `mouseover` event will not fire on `svg`, it will only bubble up to it and that too _only_ if some underlying element doesn't unwittingly stop it's propagation. Have you tried this with the `mouseenter` event as well? Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter

Comment: @musically_ut yes. same problem on click events. see my edit

Comment: I don't think jQuery can define event handlers for SVG elements because it doesn't use the required namespace. Since you've tagged the question (or someone has) d3.js, could you not use d3.js event handling instead? That does work with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had an SVG rectangle that was blocking the path elements beneath it. When I hide the SVG rectangle overlaying its children, then the children (which were blocked) register click events.